# How to access JSON values(array) in various tables

Tags: iphone, json

I am getting results from JSON,

```
NSDictionary *pname=[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ax21:productName"];
NSString *str = [pname objectForKey:@"$"];
i++;
[detArray addObject:str];
[tblviewhome reloadData];
```

and calling it in table like

```
cell.textLabel.text = [detArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

this displays data in 4 sections.This is displaying data perfectly .
JSON connectivity and table are in same class.
but how to access this data in another table which is in another view controller.

I hope i made my self clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways either take a global array or take two local arrays .

Taking  first case of global array fill that array as you are filling right now and whenever you push to another class just load the data of that array into the another tableview .

Now in the second case whenever you are take twe array one in which you have got your data and n the other array in view in which there is another table view and when u push from  this view   just pass data form the first array to the other array .
Hope this helps.